# Sharing common variables within a Container View

Tags: swiftui

Scenario: 
I had a large view that I want to break up into a container view having couple of child views.

So each view has its own .string file.
The paradigm: dissemination of processes from one file to the children as a 'collective'.

The container view would act as the hub, the intelligence.

I don't want this to be overly complicated; merely modularizing the logic in discrete parts for easy maintenance.

**Problem:**  I can only go *one-way* **@State ---> @Binding** between struct Views without going thru a Class  Object. 
          Is there a way to return values; e.g., two-way data exchange? 

 That is, child views sharing their common views with the parent/container?

```
 View1  |  View2          &   View2     |   View1 <br/>
@State -->@Binding (data) & @Binding <-- @State (result)?
```

I must I use some sort of singleton class object for the data exchange?

Again, I'm for simplicity of design vs a large single struct View.

Comment: See if this helps you: https://www.vadimbulavin.com/passing-data-between-swiftui-views/. Binding is the way a child returns a value. To call a parent from a child, you'd typically use a callback or you can also use [`onChange(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/onchange(of:perform:)) of the bound value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding ***is*** the way a value is "returned" from a child to parent. If the child didn't update the value (i.e. just one-way `parent -> child`, then you wouldn't need a binding - just pass the variable in an init).

```
struct Child: View {
   @Binding var num: Int
   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         Text("\(num)")
         Button("increase") { self.num += 1 }
      }
   }
}

struct Parent: View {
   @State var sharedNum: Int = 0
   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         Text("\(sharedNum)")
         Child(num: $sharedNum)
         Child(num: $sharedNum)
      }
      .onChange(of: sharedNum) { print("shared num", $0) } // iOS14 required
   }
}
```

Both children and the parent would display the same number regardless of which of the children changed it.

---

But, sometimes a child might need to notify the parent not necessarily through a value change. Then you could use a callback:

```
struct Child: View {
   var onClick: (Int) -> Void

   var body: some View {
      Button("generate random") { 
         onClick(Int.random(1...100))
      }
   }
}

struct Parent: View {
   var body: some View {
      Child {
         print("new random", $0)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I got a " Child(num: @sharedNum)"  <- Expected expression in list of expressions

Comment: typo... I just changed it. It should be of course `Child(num: $sharedNum)`

Comment: I just discovered that myself; but my comment had timed out before changes.
Thanks a ton!